# Reshaping a 5D array to a 2D - different results in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 5D array of shape (5, 2, 40, 100, 32), which is a dataset. 5 and 40 refer to the number of classes and samples per each class, respectively. The correct conversion will mean that we will have 200 (5*40) files in total, where the first 40 refer to class 1, the next 40 to class 2, etc. I want to convert the matrix to a 2D array in order to apply ML methods. The code in Python seems to be working, while the code in Matlab is probably wrong.

This is the code I use in Python, which seems to be the correct solution:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = 'data\*.mat'
path2 = 'new'
files = glob.glob(path)

data = scipy.io.loadmat(r"C:\Users\danny\OneDrive\Desktop\spectrogram.mat")

for i in data:
    if '__' not in i and 'readme' not in i:
        data_new = data[i].reshape(200, 6400)
        pd.DataFrame(data_new).to_csv(r"C:\Users\danny\OneDrive\Desktop\file.csv", header=None,
                                      index=None)
```

However, I want to try the same code in Matlab as the file is originally a *.mat file, and I do not need to convert it to a *.csv file. Please see this code:

```
Mp = permute(spectrogram,[1 3 2 4 5]);
Md = reshape(Mp,[],2,100,32);
K = reshape(Md, 200, 6400)
```

However, when I look into the two matrices, they are not the same as they are supposed to be. In addition, the ML methods work with high accuracy for the Python generated matrix, while the Matlab generated matrix shows very poor results. This makes me think that the Python code is correct, but I am not sure how I can apply this to Matlab.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76822159/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.